# sending non form values in Jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I send all form values using the following in Jquery:

```
$.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize(), function(data)
```

Is there anyway I can send a non form value along with the post, for ex the id name of a div? I don't get any response when I try the following:

```
$.post('get-offers.php', {$("#offerForm").serialize(), lastid: $(".box").attr("id") }, function(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#offerForm").serialize()` returns a text string in standard URL-encoded notation, so you could just append to it.

```
$.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize()+'&lastid='+$(".box").attr("id"), function(data)
```

Comment: `serialize()` returns a string. What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data onto the end of the serialized form data

```
var data = $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + $(".box").attr("id")

post('get-offers.php', data, function(data){})
```

Comment: Exactly. jQuery serialize() just makes a query string out of it. All you have to do is append to the query string, like any other.